# Auto Height of Flow Layout Panel if controls are added

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using flow layouut panel with flow direction left to right. In my application I have to add some buttons on flow layout panel dynamically on run time and I'm not sure how many controls (buttons) will be added on flowlayout panel.

How can I auto adjust the height of flow layout panel if controls added (buttons) overflow the row in flowlayout panel?

Eg. If there are 8 controls to be added on panel and 5 controls can be fitted into one row of flowlayout panel. For the remaining 3 controls, I would require to increase the height of panel so that these 3 controls can be shown on oanel in next row.

Note: Scrollbars will not be used in this and height of the control will be exact the number of rows required to fill the controls

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CreateMainCategories()
        'MsgBox(Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.Rows.Count)
        Try

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.TblItemMainCategoryDataGridView.Rows
                Dim btnMainCatBtn As New Button

                With btnMainCatBtn
                    .Name = ("btn" & row.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value).ToString.Replace(" ", "_")
                    .Text = row.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value
                    .Height = Me.FpnlMainCategoryBtnContainer.Height - 15
                    .Width = 150
                    '.Dock = DockStyle.Left
                    .Font = New Font("Calibri", 15)
                    .ForeColor = Color.White
                    .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
                    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                    '.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText
                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

                    'If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\MainCategory\" & row.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG") Then 'remove the image from directory if user remove the image
                    '    .Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\MainCategory\" & row.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value & ".JPEG")
                    'Else
                    '    .Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\" & "imgEmpty.png")
                    'End If

                End With

                Me.FpnlMainCategoryBtnContainer.Controls.Add(btnMainCatBtn)

                AddHandler btnMainCatBtn.Click, AddressOf MainCategoryButtonFeatures

                'add panel
                Dim SubCatBtnContPnl As New MyControls.MyFlowLayoutPanel
                With SubCatBtnContPnl
                    .Name = ("pnl" & row.Cells("MainCategoryName").Value).ToString.Replace(" ", "_")
                    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                    .TopColor = Color.Red
                    .BottomColor = Color.Black
                    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                    .AutoScroll = True
                    .WrapContents = False
                    .FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight
                End With

                'MsgBox(SubCatBtnContPnl.Name)
                Me.pnlMainCatPnlContainer.Controls.Add(SubCatBtnContPnl)


            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code that recreates the problem for us.

Comment: I have added the code by editing question. Please have a look.

Comment: Anchor the FLP (Left, Top, Right) and set `AutoSize = True`. It will keep its Width and resize its Height. BTW, you, apparently, have two FlowLayoutPanels: one that receives the Buttons and another one, added to the unknown `pnlMainCatPnlContainer`, which is not hosting anything, or it looks like it doesn't have a function.

Comment: You can ignore the second panel that is similar to the above one. If i get the answer of above it will also work for below panel. The solution you have provided has one problem as when we set the anchor peooert and auto size propert true, it remove its dock property as at the same time I also want to panel to be dock on top on its container.

Comment: Docking to Top or anchoring Left, Top, Right is the same thing. The result doesn't change.

Comment: You can't have both Docking and Anchoring.  You have to pick one that works best for your layout.

Comment: @Jimi Thank Your for your suggestion that worked for me. Since I have used this on the base panel which I already had on my window form. I am facing an issue where I have to add base panel on run time. As per my new scenario---I have a base panel which is added manually on window form and On rum time I have to add new another Flow layout panel on that panel. Once I add the flowlayout panel then I have to add some buttons on that flowlayout panel where I want to have these both panels in autosize mode whenever the number of buttons added increase on the flowlayout panel. Please help.